# How is Cakkhupālattheravatthu pronounced exactly?

Tags: pali-language, early-buddhism, pali

I read stories about the monk called Cakkhupālattheravatthu, but still don't know how this name is pronounced? Can anyone please tell me the exact pronunciation of this name or word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is Cakkhupālattheravatthu pronounced exactly?

In the video [*"Dhammapada Verse One: Mind Precedes All Things"*](https://youtu.be/lZZiE-EofAE?t=5m19s), by Ven. Yuttadhammo, the pronunciation can be heard at 5:21 min. into the video.

Answer (score 1):

I often use google translate. You can [listen here](https://translate.google.co.th/?hl=th&tab=wT&authuser=0#hi/th/%E0%A4%9A%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%96%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A5%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A5%E0%A5%81).

Comment: Note that in this instance at least the pronunciation of Google Translate is incorrect.

Comment: No, google translate is right. But your ears must be the advance. The Thai language is not indo-europian language, but Hindi and Nepāli are. You can use Wikipedia to check the phonetic of that language. They still as alike as Pali.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari#Consonants. But Thai is difference very much. I am a Thai nationality. Thai language is a barrier to learn Pali.

Comment: Its pronunciation of Cakkhupāla is right, but in "ttheravatthu" it misses the "a" between "r" and "v". But if you split up (“cakkhupālatthe rav atthu”), it becomes ok: [listen here](https://translate.google.co.th/?hl=th&tab=wT&authuser=0#hi/th/%E0%A4%9A%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%96%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A5%E0%A5%87%20%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%8D%20%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A5%E0%A5%81%20%0A%E0%A4%9A%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%96%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A5%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%A4%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A5%E0%A5%81)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR Thank you very much. You're right. Your answer gives me the way to develop my tipitaka pronouncer software.